# lisp: describing every external thing in a package

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm sure the answer is obvious, but I'm banging my head against this one. I'm trying to describe every externally defined thing in a LISP package. The following (SBCL) code prints the symbols just fine:

```
(require "sb-posix")
(do-external-symbols (single-symbol 'sb-posix)
  (prin1 single-symbol) (terpri))
```

... so I was hoping that something like this would do the job, but it doesn't:

```
(require "sb-posix")
(do-external-symbols (single-symbol 'sb-posix)
  (describe sb-posix:single-symbol))
```

The first two lines of the error message I get are:

```
Unhandled SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR:
  Symbol "SINGLE-SYMBOL" not found in the SB-POSIX package.
```

What obvious correction am I missing?

Comment: Remove the package prefix from `sb-posix:single-symbol`. The variable name isn't in the `sb-posix`-package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code binds a variable `single-symbol` to the value of each external symbol in sb-posix. The symbol naming the variable is in the current package (as specified by `cl:*package*`), not in the sb-posix package, and should not be referenced with an sb-posix package prefix.